# can find inequality with this sum?

Tags: inequality

I have prove this 
$$x(1-x)=\dfrac{1}{6}-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{(2n\pi x)}}{n^2},x\in[0,1]$$

I do not care about the proof of this equation now, because it is not difficult to prove(using the Fourier series proof), my current question is about this sum $\dfrac{\cos{(2n\pi x})}{n^2}$ and whether there is an inequality, I do not know if it has been studied?
 since the  $B_{2}(x)=x^2-x+\dfrac{1}{6}$ be the 2nd Bernoulli polynomial,
we can find the best  $C(n)\to 0,n\to+\infty$following
$$\left|B_{2}(x)\cdot\pi^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\cos{(2k\pi x})}{k^2}\right|\le C(n)$$

Comment: What is the interval for $x$? The expansion of $x(1-x)$ is certainly not valid for all real $x$. If you take $x \in [0,1]$ then  the last inequality holds with $C=1+3\pi^{2}$ for example.

Comment: How to prove this $C=1+3\pi^2?$,it is old reslut?Thanks

Comment: $|B_n(x)| \leq 1+1+\frac 1 6 <3$ and $\frac {|\cos(2n\pi x)|} {n^{2}}\leq \frac 1 {n^{2}} \leq 1$.

Comment: Is there such a thing as "Fourier series with remainder" (as there is for Taylor series)?